# How do I both store unicode characters and output them to a file?

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, localization, c++17

This is my input function:

```
template <typename T>
T getUserInput(std::string prompt = "")
{
    T input;
    std::cout << prompt;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cin >> input;
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    return input;
}
```

And I call it and write it to a file this way:

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
    std::ofstream testfile{ "testfile.txt" };
    std::string test = getUserInput<std::string>("Please write a string: ");
    testfile << test << '\n';
```

However, I speak Spanish, so sometimes I want to write characters like 'á', 'ñ', '¿', etc., but they get ommited or unrecognizable. If I write:

> Mi señor, ¿Cómo va todo?

The file outputs:

> Mi se¤or, ¨C¢mo va todo?

As you can see in my code, I have already tried to use setlocale to spanish, and it works whenever I want to output those characters mannualy via std::cout, but I can't store them. I've also tried using std::wstring instead of std::string but I can't get getline to output to it. How can I do it? By the way, I'm coding on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows you can use [_setmode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tw4k6df8(v%3Dvs.140)):

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


template <typename T>
T getUserInput(std::wstring prompt = "")
{
    T input;
    std::wcout << prompt;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::wstring>)
    {
        std::getline(std::wcin, input);
    }
    else
    {
        std::wcin >> input;
        std::wcin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    return input;
}

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_WTEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);

    std::wofstream testfile{ "testfile.txt" };
    std::wstring test = getUserInput<std::wstring>(L"Please write a string: ");
    testfile << test << '\n';
}
```

Note this is compiled with MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

use std::wstring with std::wcin to get wchar string from input [wcin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin)